# Limit node reference to 1 per user & per referenced node, Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I am trying to limit the creation of a node reference to 1 per user and per referenced node. 
More specifically: I have a content type named Debate and another one called Vote. Vote has a node reference field (from URL widget) called *debate_ref* to the Debate type. What i'm trying to achieve is ***for each user and for each debate to have only one vote*** 
i.e. when a user tries to create a 2nd vote node on the same debate node then he will recieve a message saying "You have already voted!".

"Unique field" module does the job but after the user attempts to save his 2nd vote node. **What i would like to achieve is to deny access to the user who attempts to re-visit the "node/add/vote/nid" form if he has already voted for the specific debate.**

Any help?

Comment: Do you use a custom module ? Or Panels at least ? I'm afraid you won't be able to do that without at least Panels.

Comment: Hi Greg. Well i created a costum module using the code from this link: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14504/limit-the-reviews-on-product-content-type but i can't make it work. The panels idea sounds interesting. Can you please give me some feedback?

Comment: Feedback given as answer :)

Comment: How would users get to to `node/add/vote/nid` the second time? By typing it in manually?

Comment: Either manually or by clicking the corresponding "vote now" node reference link on each debate node.

Comment: Rather than displaying an error (or redirecting/whatever) when a user who's already voted clicks the _vote now_ link, I'd focus on not displaying the link to them at all. (And you can relax knowing that _unique field_ will prevent anyone who manually types the URL in from being able to double vote.)

Comment: Nice thought. How can you dissapear the link when the user has voted?

Comment: How do you currently add the link? I'd use a preprocess function to do the check and set up variables as appropriate for the template.

Comment: I'm using views to show the link as an image link.

Comment: In that case you could use hook_preprocess_views_view_field() and change the template variable $output. Is there any particular reason you're using a View to display the link?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. I'm using a view because i found it to be the easiest way to have an image node reference link. I'll try this soon and report back. Meanwhile any other suggestions are fully appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's a number of ways of doing what you want without using Views. The simplest I'd argue is to create a variable in hook_preprocess_node() for the vote link, and then use display suite and [add a preprocess field](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvFP16PJt4c) linked to that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use hook on form_alter inside a custom module :

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'vote_node_form') {
    global $user;
    $nid = explode('/', current_path());
    $nid = end($nid);
    // I'm sure that next part can be done waaaaaaay better
    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('entity_type', 'vote', '=')
    ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=');
    $query->join('your_entity_ref_field_table', 'e', 'n.nid = e.entity_id');
    $query->condition('your_reference_column', $nid, '=');
    $query->groupBy('e.entity_id')->execute();
    // I'd advice to do a dpm($query->fetchAssoc();) to check if I didn't make a mistake         :)

    if(!empty($query)) {
            // We force the user to go on any page if he has already casted a vote on that debate (you can i.e create a page with a word of explanation)
            drupal_goto('/');
            //or do whatever you want here
    } else {
            // If not, we let him go to the normal node creation page
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this in the template.php. My node reference field is: "field_debate_ref" with field table: field_data_field_debate ref and column: field_debate_ref_nid. I get errors each time i try to vote:PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM node n INNER JOIN field_data_field_debate_ref e ON n.entity_id = e.entity_' at line 1: SELECT FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {field_data_field_debate_ref} e ON n.entity_id.....

Comment: My bad : it's not n.entity_id = e.entity_id, it's `n.nid = e.entity_id` :) . I edited.

Comment: Sorry man. Still getting pdoexception error pointing at line 108 where the "$query->groupBy('e.entity_id')->execute();" is. I added the code i'm using at my initial question. Have a look maybe you'll get a clearer view.

Comment: maybe simply $query->groupBy(e.entity_id'); $query->execute();

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late to change the specs, but have you considered using [Flags](http://drupal.org/project/flag) with each flag counting as a vote? It seems to cover most of the uses you refer here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i'm just correcting Greg's code. So here it is:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'vote_node_form') {
global $user;
$nid = explode('/', current_path());
$nid = end($nid);
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid'))
->condition('type', 'vote', '=')
->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=');
$query->join('field_data_field_debate_ref', 'e', 'n.nid = e.entity_id');
$query->condition('field_debate_ref_nid', $nid, '=');
$result = $query->groupBy('e.entity_id')->execute()->fetchField(); 
if(!empty($result)) {
        drupal_goto('/');
   } else {
  }
 }
}
```

It's working perfectly now limiting a vote node to 1 per user & per debate node. It can be used as a costum module or directly in template.php and the best (i think): as a php selector for a panel variant of the node/add form, with some minor changes of course.

The other solution is indeed  the Flags module as mariomc mentions, but only the 3x dev branch where fields are permitted to be added to flags basically transforming them into content types that can be used for my purpose as votes, therefore having 1 vote per debate per user.

Comment: Great ! Sorry for all the errors on my original code :)

Comment: I'd be a bit careful with this code. It doesn't check $nid; it hardcodes field table names; it doesn't use EntityFieldQuery; it issues a drupal_goto() in a hook (potentially preventing other modules' hooks from firing).