# Disable the Fivestar widget after the first vote

Tags: 7, rules, rating, userpoints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to limit a user to one vote when using Fivestar?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/how-to-limit-a-user-to-one-vote-when-using-fivestar)

I am a newbie to drupal. I am using Drupal 7, fivestar, userpoints and voting rules modules in my intranet site. I created new rules by using the Rules module to award points to the content author based on the rating (no. of stars etc.) provided by the logged in users. This is working fine.

But the problem is, whenever the logged in user clicked the fivestar widget, an event fires and the content author is getting points based on the rules defined. To resolve this, I want to disable the fivestar widget after the logged in user clicks the fivestar widget once.
How can this be done?

I am using the following modules:

- Fivestar 7.x-2.0-alpha2
- Voting API 7.x-2.6
- Userpoints 7.x-1.0
- Voting Rules 7.x-1.0-alpha1
- Rules 7.x-2.1

Comment: see this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/how-to-limit-a-user-to-one-vote-when-using-fivestar/36171#36171

Comment: Using hook_form_alter() you could unset() the Fivestar field for logged in users or the node author I believe.

Comment: @mohammed Anwar. Thanks for your link. I updated my reply in the linked page. Could you please have a look at it?