# How to hide Fivestar rating field after first comment?

Tags: 7, rules, comments, rating

The accepted answer on [How to limit a user to one vote when using Fivestar?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/how-to-limit-a-user-to-one-vote-when-using-fivestar) doesn't work for me, but the author hasn't provided a solution yet, so I felt this is worth a new question.

My goal is exactly the same as the one in the article mentioned above: I'd like to hide the Fivestar rating field (called *field_stars*) in the comment form when a user comments on a node on which he/she's already commented.

Is there another solution (for example with the Rules and Flags modules)?

---

**Edit:** I already have a flag called *Commented* on my site and a rule that flags a node on behalf of the commentator when someone commented on it (which works perfectly). I'd really like to use it to fix this problem. I tried something, based on the information I found [here](https://drupal.org/node/305086):

```
function hiderating_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $flag = flag_get_flag('commented') or die('no "commented" flag defined');
  if ($form_id == "comment_node_stuff_form") {
   if ($form['#node']->uid == $user->uid OR $flag->is_flagged($form['#node']->uid, $user->uid)) { 
      unset($form['field_stars']);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything (I don't get any errors either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nearly had the answer in my **edit**. The code should have been

```
function hiderating_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $flag = flag_get_flag('commented') or die('no "commented" flag defined');
  if ($form_id == "comment_node_stuff_form") {
   if ($form['#node']->uid == $user->uid OR $flag->is_flagged($form['#node']->nid, $user->uid)) { 
      unset($form['field_stars']);
    }
  }
}
```

So, the only thing that was wrong was `$flag->is_flagged($form['#node']->uid`. It should have been `$flag->is_flagged($form['#node']->nid`.

Many thanks to @jerdiggity on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079073/how-to-hide-fivestar-rating-field-programatically-after-first-comment)!

Answer (score 0):

In your node.tpl.php you should have the following code

```
hide($content['field_fivestar']);
print singlerating_print_rating($node->nid, $content['field_fivestar']);
```

I presume field_fivestar is the fivestar field you are using and not field_fivestar_rating

Comment: I tried that before and it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the result you get when you add that code?

Comment: Nothing happens: no errors, no nothing.

Comment: could you do one thing add the following code in your node.tpl.php

print "<pre>" . $content . "</pre>"; and send me the out put that you get in your screen.

Comment: Should something be displayed on the content pages? I can't see anything there...

Comment: what is your star filed name is it field_stars? if it is then the code should be 

hide($content['field_stars']);
print singlerating_print_rating($node->nid, $content['field_stars']);

Comment: Yes, it's called "field_stars". I changed it, but still no result. Can we perhaps work on with my edit (see question)? Since you helped me with that code snippet, maybe that'll work...

Comment: are you certain that you are using the correct node.tpl file?

Comment: themes/mytheme/templates/node.tpl as mention in my question. I'm using 'mytheme', so I guess that's the correct file.