# How to hide rating field when adding comment to own node?

Tags: 7, entities, comments, rating

On my website, users can rate nodes with the Fivestar module while adding a comment. In other words, the rating field (called 'stars') is part of the comment. Now, I'd like to hide the rating field for users when they comment on their own nodes *(or when they already have commented before - see: [How to hide Fivestar rating field after first comment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90627/how-to-limit-users-to-single-vote-with-fivestar))*.

How can I do that?

---

**Edit 1:** I applied [this patch](https://drupal.org/files/fivestar-disallow-rate-own-content-189527-97.patch) (patch 97 on https://drupal.org/node/189527), but my problem still isn't solved. I now have the following option at *Administration > Structure > Content types > MyArticle > Comment fields*:

[image: Vote on own comment]

But after clearing caches and creating new content, the rating field is still displayed when I add a new comment.

---

**Edit 2:** I sent an e-mail to the patch's author and he answered this:

> The purpose of the patch I created is to prevent a user from rating
>   their own node.  I believe the problem you are having with this patch
>   is that, since the fivestar field is on the comment, that the patch I
>   wrote would probably reference the comment itself (as the entity id)
>   instead of the node - freely allowing someone to vote.

---

**Edit 3:** I tried to solve my problem with a custom module called 'hiderating'. This is the code I'm using:

```
function hiderating_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == "comment_node_stuff_form") {
   if ($form['#node']->uid == $user->uid) {
      $form['field_stars']['#access'] = 0;
      }
      else {
      $form['field_stars']['#required'] = 1;
      }
    }
}
```

I made the 'Stars' field not required from the interface. The code is nearly working: the 'Stars' field isn't displayed when one comments on his/her own node, but unfortunately, it isn't turned to 'Required' when one comments on someone else's node. In other words, my code's `else` part doesn't work properly.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you check the issue queue, we have a issue for this. https://drupal.org/node/189527. Patch 97 was the fix for that.

Comment: @Gladiator: I applied the patch you mentioned, but it doesn't work (see edit 1). The patch's author Travis thought that it's possibly not suitable for my problem (see edit 2).

Comment: why do you need an else part?

Comment: @Mohammed Shameem: well, I'd like the rating field to be required, but when I mark it as 'required' via the interface, people adding a comment to their own node get an error, because they didn't rate it (the field was hidden).

Comment: have you tried using unset($form['field_stars']); instead of $form['field_stars']['#access'] = 0; and also make the field as required and remove the else part

Comment: @MohammedShameem: That works! Finally solved, thank you so much! If you post it as an answer, I'll check it as the solution.

Comment: Have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `unset($form['field_stars']);` instead of `$form['field_stars']['#access'] = 0;`

You can keep the fields as required and also remove the else condition.

So your final code would be something like this

```
function hiderating_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == "comment_node_stuff_form") {
   if ($form['#node']->uid == $user->uid) {
      unset($form['field_stars']);
      }
    }
}
```