# How to hide a Fivestar field in a comment when the user didn't vote?

Tags: 7, entities, comments, rating

The comments on my articles have a Fivestar field called 'Stars', but rating nodes isn't always required (see: [How to hide rating field when adding comment to own node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/how-to-hide-rating-field-when-adding-comment-to-own-node)). When the user didn't rate the node on which he/she is reacting, 0 stars (not saved in the database) are now being displayed in his/her comment, but I don't really like that.

[image: Comment without rating]

How can I hide the stars when the user didn't vote?

---

**Edit:** I'm trying to find a workaround with flags. I've created a flag called 'Reaction on own' and a rule that flags a comment when the comment's author equals the author of the commented node. In my case, it's sufficient that the 'Stars' field isn't displayed when a comment is flagged with 'Reaction on own'. This is the code of my custom module:

```
function hiderating_comment_view($comment) {
  $flag = flag_get_flag('reaction_on_own');
  if ($flag->is_flagged($comment->cid)){
    unset($comment->field_stars);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. What's going wrong?

---

**Note:** In fact, the edit above isn't entirely true in my case, because 'zero' stars appear when a user reacts on his/her article *or* when the user has commented before. I've provided an answer for both cases.

Comment: Please check if the 'no value' value is stored in a different way from the '0 star' value so I can help you ^^

Comment: @Shyghar: When users leave a comment without voting, there's no '0' value saved to the database, if that's what you mean.

Comment: `if ($comment == "comment_node_article") {` is incorrect has `hook_comment_view` is passed the comment object, not a string in that parameter. It will never evaluate to true.

Comment: @David Thomas: Thanks for your reaction. I don't really understand what you wrote there, but I could deduct that my code isn't working. Do you have any suggestions for improvement? I'm new to PHP, so I don't know a lot about using hooks. I've just tried something, because nobody seems to know a solution for a over week now.

Comment: @Jeroen tentative solution added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm excited to announce that I finally found a working solution! It turned out to be a bit more difficult than I had assumed in the beginning: I had to work with flags, rules and a custom module. Perhaps it was also possible to achieve this without flags, but they can come in handy elsewhere on one's website (e.g. for granting userpoints to users), so that's a little bonus.

**Step 1:** Create a flag for comments 'First reaction on article'.

**Step 2:** Create a flag for articles 'Commented on this article'.

**Step 3:** Create a rule similar the one with the following settings:

```
{ "rules_new_reaction_on_article" : {
    "LABEL" : "New reaction on article",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert--comment_node_article" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "comment:author" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } },
          "operation" : "OR"
        }
      },
      { "NOT flag_flagged_node" : {
          "flag" : "commented-on-this-article",
          "node" : [ "comment:node" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "comment:author" ]
        }
      },
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "comment:author" ], "value" : [ "comment:node:author" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_flagnode" : {
          "flag" : "commented-on-this-article",
          "node" : [ "comment:node" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "comment:author" ],
          "permission_check" : 1
        }
      },
      { "flag_flagcomment" : {
          "flag" : "first-reaction-on-article",
          "comment" : [ "comment" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "comment:author" ],
          "permission_check" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** Create a custom module 'Hiderating':

```
function hiderating_comment_view($comment) {
  $flag = flag_get_flag('first-reaction-on-article');
  $uid = db_query('SELECT n.uid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {comment} c ON c.nid = n.nid WHERE c.cid = :cid', array(':cid' => $comment->cid))->fetchField();
  if ($comment->uid == $uid OR !$flag->is_flagged($comment->cid, $comment->uid)){
    $comment->content['field_stars']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach like this (untested) but may work

```
/**
 * Implements hook_comment_view
 */
function hiderating_comment_view($comment) {
  if($flag = flag_get_flag('reaction_on_own')){
    // Debug comment to find field to hide, check dblog / watchdog
    debug($comment);
    if (!$flag->is_flagged($comment->cid)){
      unset($comment->field_stars);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested it, but, although it doesn't return any errors, the 'empty' stars are still there after clearing caches and adding new comments.

Comment: OK, you'll need to dump out the comment to find where the relevant field to unset is. Answer updated with debug info

Comment: Hmm, odd that should be fine there. You can try debug() instead and check the watchdog log in admin. Otherwise need another way to determine flag info on comment.

Comment: I thought the error we discussed earlier was possibly a result of a corrupt database, but even with a fresh installation I get the error "Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in C:\wamp\www\mysite\includes\common.inc on line 7517" when I add the `debug` line. Do you know what causes this? I'd really like the code to work...